# Expected behavior when Private Memory Limit in IIS exceeds machine RAM

Tags: c#, iis, memory

So I have a couple of questions re: Private Memory Limit in IIS using a C# web app.

When we set the Private Memory Limit to 0, per the docs [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx) it should have no limit.  However we saw behavior that the app would trigger an IIS reset when reaching approximately 60% of the machine RAM which seems counter intuitive.  Does this grok?

The second issue is expected behavior when the Private Memory Limit is set to a value that exceeds the amount of RAM available on the machine.  A co-worker solved the above problem by setting the Private Memory Limit above the system memory and it did perform well.  However this seems like it could have ramifications about proper GC times.

For example if the system RAM is 32 GB and the memory limit is set to 35, will it not trigger Gargbage Collection when it gets close to 32 because it THINKS it can get to 35?  Or are we guaranteed a garbage collection will happen before then?

Additionally this requires a config change if you ever change the size of the machine (we are an AWS shop so this can happen at a relatively high frequency).

Comment: Any reason why it's using so much memory in the first place?

Comment: The application stores a very large amount of data in its in memory cache (that's a whole other bag of worms to be sorted out).  But this cache is always currently holding approximately 30GB of RAM but can fluctuate by about 5% over time and throughout the day

Comment: Ah no worries.  One way to keep IIS happy is to move the cache to a different non-IIS process and talk to it via your favourite IPC mechanism or shared memory.  That would make the memory used by IIS purely for your webby stuff and would be a lot smaller

Comment: Yeah we are doing that long term and that project is in progress, just want to get the stop gap time to a safe production enviornment

Comment: Excellent.  Wishing you well

Comment: Are you sure it's happening at 60% each time or is the `timed` recycle kicking in?

Comment: @webnoob that's a good question, I'll look at that offline and see if that is causing issues

Comment: Ok, np. The timed recycle is active by default so that would be my first point of call.

Comment: First, which Windows release are you using? Some versions might need to be patched. The description of "trigger an IIS reset" and "trigger Gargbage Collection" are totally irrelevant. IIS application pool recycle based on private memory usage would trigger neither IIS reset nor GC. Your understanding of IIS process model and .NET memory management is far from enough and you probably should open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com so that Microsoft support can collect the required information to troubleshoot.

Comment: @LexLi - I get the impression he means the IIS process for that website (i.e `w3wp`) is restarting when he says `IIS Reset` and `Garbage Collection`.

Comment: @webnoob anyway with the low quality description above it would be impossible to get a conclusion on the cause (as even the symptoms are not clear).

Comment: @webnoob the timed recycle is turned off.  And yes I did mean that the IIS process reset when it was at 60% of RAM available on the machine.

@ LexLi I am trying to understand if the IIS process will get rid of un-used memory as it approaches the system memory even if the private memory size is greater than the system memory.  Is that not clear?

Comment: Check the windows event log, it could be your application crashing at 60% memory for one reason or another. The windows event viewer will show a log for the w3wp process fatal error causing it to terminate - If you see one of these, it's not IIS, it's the app.